# Converting Web of Science ID to pubmed or DOI

Tags: data, bibliometrics

I have downloaded a set of articles from Web of Science using their API.

Each article contains its WOS (web of science ID), but the entries for the DOI identifier are incomplete (i.e., not all articles have a DOI).

Is there a way to convert the WOS number to get the DOI or PubMed ID for each article?

Comment: Did you try uploading these articles in a reference manager program such as Zotero. If I remember well it can fetch data based on WOS and will then return all other known IDs, such as DOI/pubmed/etc...

Comment: That's a good idea, but I'm not sure whether I can simply import the data that I obtain using the web of science API. Do you think there might be a way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can manually put parts of the citation into https://search.crossref.org/ and it will give you back the doi.

Alternatively, you could migrate your WOS bibliography into Mendeley using the steps in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FqtAPRZaz2U . I just started using Mendeley (by Elsevier) and have imported my EndNote references pretty easily. I was able to then find the missing PMIDs for a paper I was writing.

Good luck!